# Recursion function to count no. of steps in tower of hanoi

Tags: recursion, towers-of-hanoi

Write a recursive function which returns number of steps required to solve the tower of Hanoi problem for N discs.

Input
n=3
Output
7

Here is the code-

```
private static int counttoh(int n,String T1,String T2,String T3)
 {int count=0;

     if(n==0)
     return 1; 


     count+=counttoh(n-1,T1,T3,T2);
     count+=counttoh(n-1,T3,T2,T1);

     return count;
 }
```

My function counttoh is giving 4 as the output, if I am doing return count-1 it is giving 1 , can anyone help me with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solving tower of Hanoi, need to move all rings on top of the bottom one (n - 1), then move the bottom one (+ 1), then move all the others back on top (n - 1 again).

```
public static int countMoves(int n) {

    if (n == 0) return 0;

    // count(n-1) + 1 + count(n-1)
    return 2 * countMoves(n - 1) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int move(int n, char source, char destination, char spare)
{ int count = 1;
if (n==1){
    printf("\n\nMove a disc from %c to %c", source, destination);
}
else{
    count += move(n-1, source, spare, destination);
             move(1, source, destination, spare);
    count += move(n-1, spare, destination, source);
}
return count;
}

int main()
{
int n, steps;
char A, B, C;
printf("Enter the number of disc :- ");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("\nHere A is source, B is destination, C is spare.");
steps = move(n, 'A', 'B', 'C');
printf("\n\nNumber of steps taken is %d", steps);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!

Answer (score 1):

Tower of Hanoi with number of steps - recursion method
Code C++

```
long long toh(int N, int from, int to, int aux) {
    int count=1;
    if(N==0){
        return 0;
    }
    count+=toh(N-1, from, aux, to);
    cout<<"move disk "<<N<<" from rod "<<from<<" to rod "<<to<<endl;
    count+=toh(N-1, aux, to, from);

    return count;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public long toh(int N, int from, int to, int aux) 
{
    int count = 1;
        
    if(N == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("move disk "+N+" from rod "+from+" to rod "+to);
        return count;
    }
    else
    {
        count +=toh(N-1, from, aux, to);
        System.out.println("move disk "+N+" from rod "+from+" to rod "+to);
        count +=toh(N-1, aux, to, from);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

long long toh(int N, int s, int d, int h) {
long long cnt=1;       // to count number of steps

```
    if(N==0) {
        return 0;
    }
    cnt += toh(N-1,s,h,d);
    cout<<"move disk "<<N<<" from rod "<<s<< " to rod "<<d<<endl;
    cnt += toh(N-1,h,d,s);

    return cnt; 
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int moveAndCount(string source, string spare, string destination, int n, int count);
int main( ) {
   int n = 0;
   cout << "Enter n : " ;
   cin >> n;
   cout << "List and count of steps = " << endl;
   cout <<  moveAndCount("Source", "Spare", "Destination", n, 0) << endl;
   return 0;
}
int moveAndCount(string source, string spare, string destination, int n, int count) {
   if(n == 0)  return count; 
   else {
        count = moveAndCount(source, destination, spare, n-1, count);
        cout << "Move " << source << " to  " << destination << endl;
        count = 1 + moveAndCount(spare, source, destination, n-1, count);
      }
  return count;
}
```

Counting starts after the print.

```cpp
count = 1 + moveAndCount(spare, source, destination, n-1, count)
```

But how many steps were made in the next recursive step?

```
  count = moveAndCount(source, destination, spare, n-1, count)
```

In summary the whole counting is just sum of three parts

- Movement of one disk.
- Movement of N-1 Stack from Source to Spare.
- Movement of the same N-1 Stack from Spare to Destination.

---

Note : Stack of N is similar to stack of N-1 with just One extra Disk.

- If there was no requirement for the printing the steps in that case:

```
count = 1 + moveAndCount(spare, source, destination, n-1, count) + moveAndCount(source, destination, spare, n-1, count);
```

- Note : The counting is similar to SICP's Count-Change example.
- To know about the recursive strategy used :
  [SICP's Lecture 1B by Prof. Sussman](https://youtu.be/V_7mmwpgJHU?list=PLE18841CABEA24090&t=2839)